# Flutter and Firebase: Get DocumentSnapShot Based On Current User ID

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here's my code to get current user documentsnapshot from database.

```
Future getCurrentUSerData() async {
     final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(currentUserId).get();

      currentUser = MyUser.fromDocument(doc);

  }
```

1. I got the currentUserId. there is no problem with that.

2.userRef is the reference to the users in firebase (`final userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');`)

3. but when I checked currentUser value, the value is  returned as null.
4. Problem - How to get the current user data based on current user id?

Comment: how are u calling `getCurrentUSerData()`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad what do you mean by calling this method? sorry for the question.I'm really new to flutter and firebase. All I did was, in the same dart file just wrote these lines to check the value is null or not.               ``` FlatButton(onPressed: () {

if(currentUser == null){

  print('No user');
} else print('user');

          }, ```

Comment: peter is asking, where are you calling this method `getCurrentUSerData` in the class? If you are not aware of what that is.. inside your build method write this before returning the widget.. await getCurrentUserData();

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(currentUserId).get();
```

to

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.doc(currentUserId).get();
```